# How to import OTR key into Pidgin?

Tags: security, pidgin

How can I import an existing OTR key (i.e. from another Pidgin instance) into Pidgin (here version 2.10.9) with installed pidgin-otr plugin?

I tried just copying `~/.purple/otr.private_key` and `~/.purple/otr.fingerprints` to the corresponding directory for the new user account, but there is no effect. Pidgin tries to generate a new key for the account.

Answer (score 0):

Use keysync to transfer OTR keys between various chat clients.

> **KeySync - One key for all of your chat apps**
>
> https://guardianproject.info/apps/keysync
>
> There are many chat apps that support OTR encryption for verifying messages. Many of us use multiple chat apps, including one for desktop and another for mobile, or one for Mac OS X and another for GNU/Linux or Windows. The trust relationships are only stored locally in the app in a format that is specific to that app. Switching between all of them means that you have to manage your trust relationships for each app that you use.
>
> KeySync addresses this problem by allowing you to sync your OTR identity and trust relationships between multiple apps, which eliminates the need to re-establish those relationships on each new client/device. It currently works with ChatSecure on Android, and Pidgin, Adium, and Jitsi on desktop.
>
> Please note: KeySync does not make it easier to have simultaneous  encrypted chats with the same account logged into multiple clients or devices. There are limitations in the OTR protocol that make this impossible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How is KeySync supposed to work to export from Pidgin on one computer to Pidgin on another?